# element.height returns visible height - I want total?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, image

**So apparently this is only happening to me - and I can't think why but if it works, I'm happy :)**

I have a full screen slideshow and I have created a function that will vertically center any images that are too large.

```
    function fixImages(){
    maxheight = $('.index-slide-container').height();
    $('.index-slide-container img').each( function(index, ele){
        if (ele.height > maxheight){
            offset = ( maxheight - ele.height ) / 2;
            $(ele).css('top', offset + 'px');
        }
    });
}
fixImages();
```

However, `ele.height` returns the height of the visible part of the image (the height of it's container, as it has `overflow:hidden`, even though when I `console.log(ele)` and expand the element, 'height' is clearly the correct value.

I have also tried `$(ele).height()`, `$(ele).css('height')`, `$(ele).outerHeight()` and `ele.clientHeight`; all of which return the same.

Thanks

Comment: height() doesn't work ? Please be more specific or give us a little fiddle, I don't understand what's the matter here...

Comment: I have added some console.log's. find it here: http://65.39.128.45/~apretty/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some tests, and $('img').height(); is giving me the right height of the picture.

If you wish to center the picture vertically why don't you use the absolute positioning with css like this for example :

```
.index-slide-container img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}
```

And than, you could set the negative margin programmatically with jQuery :

```
 $('.index-slide-container img').each( function(i, e){
     var height = $(e).height() / 2;
     $(e).css({'margin-top':'-'+height});
 });
```

Comment: with my method, I only center images when neccesary, and if the user doesn't have js enabled, then the image still works. If we do it your way, there is 50% whitespace at the top.

and it's funny, I ccan't see any reason why these methods aren't working for me :/

Comment: this isn't really a solution as I have tried `$(ele).height()` and it returns the same as `ele.height` and the rest

Comment: So ? It's the height of the image element, it should be want you wanted.. Try to do a fiddle with a specific example please.

Comment: go to http://65.39.128.45/~apretty/ and look at the console. Inside the `.each(function(ele)` I have put `console.log(ele)` and `console.log(ele.height)`. Please bear in mind `$(ele).height()` is returning the same value

Comment: Ah, there we see all heights and offset. It seems to be working well, where is the problem ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25790/discussion-between-soyuka-and-billy-mathews)